# reduce page height width when printing web page

Tags: css

I have a page that prints out perfectly fine in portrait mode.  When the page prints out in landscape, it is cutting off the last line.

The last line contains legal information and the client would like it to appear on the page if the page is printed in landscape.

Is there away I can make this possible with a media query?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your styles in:

```
@media print and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* Your styles */
}
```

Comment: I'm using IE 11.  I can't tell if I'm not adjusting the right properties or if it's an IE 11 issue.  I tried to adjust the zoom and the margins and that didn't work.  What should I be adjusting?

Comment: I adjusted the margin and font size of the div

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media print{@page {size: landscape}} to print in landscape mode

Comment: I'm like to enforce it into portrait mode.  Is that possible?